# AceGen: Assemble a user specific global array (similar to "Residual")

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I have an issue which I know is definitely solvable but I don't know how to implement this in AceGen.

Basically, I want to assemble a matrix $\mathbf{L} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{dof} \times 6}$ for a global system of equations with $n_{dof}$ degrees of freedom (without applying essential boundary conditions). This can be calculated by assembling the element contributions $\mathbf{l} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{st} \times 6}$, where $n_{st}$ is the number of nodes per element $n_{nodes}$ times the dimensionality of the problem $n_{dim}$ (e.g. 2D or 3D), therefore $n_{st} = n_{nodes} * n_{dim}$.

The assembly of $\mathbf{L}$ is done exactly how we would to it for the "Residual" $\mathbf{R}$ using the element contributions $\mathbf{r}$, only with multiple columns. Luckily, applying  `SMSD` on the energy function and exporting it using `SMSIO` does the job for the residual.

Now, I have implemented the element contribution $\mathbf{l}$ and just want to assemble it to the global array $\mathbf{L}$ of the mentioned size....

- Do I have to work with `SMSIO` right at the place where I assemble the stiffness and the residual? If yes, how do I tell AceGen that I want a custom array (which keyword?) and how would the command look like?
- Can a user defined `SMSStandardModule["Task"]` be used for this? In the documentation, it is suggested to work with task type =4 for a vector (or task type =5 for a matrix). Again, using SMSIO there is an option for exporting the `Task local vector` for the task type =4.
  I tried to use the example from the documentation and included the first column of my element vector `le`:

```
SMSIf[task == -4, SMSIO[{4, 0, 0, 0, 0}, "Export to", "Task data"]; 
  SMSReturn[];];
SMSIf[task == 4
  , SMSIO[le[[All, 1]], "Export to", 
    "Task local vector"];
  ];
```

Unfortunately, all I get is a Syntax error for the initialization (task == -4). What exactly do I have to pass as information?

Hope that I could explain my request sufficiently. Any advice is appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Frida

EDIT: I think the Syntax error is not related to the initialization but to the actual export (second SMSIO):

```
"Export to" syntax error.
User subroutine: Tasks Description: Value:   {$V[1121,1] $V[1222,1],$V[1122,1] $V[1223,1],0,$V[1124,1] $V[1222,1],$V[1125,1] $V[1223,1],0,$V[1129,1] $V[1222,1],$V[1130,1] $V[1223,1],0,$V[1131,1] $V[1222,1],...}  
Key:   Task local vector
Events: 6 BP2-4+28 SMSDB-0
Version: 7.102 MacOSX (28 Mar 20) (MMA 11.2) Module: SMSIO
See also: SMSIO  AceGen Troubleshooting  Continue
```

Answer (score 2):

Tasks subroutines can only be used to assemble vectors and square matrices. Your L matrix can be assembled by calling Tasks 6 times, for each column separately.

About the syntax error. It is an AceGen bug. You did everything right. Here is a quick solution.

```
SMSIf[task == -4, SMSIO[{4, 0, 0, 0, 0}, "Export to", "Task data"];SMSReturn[];];
SMSIf[task == 4, SMSIO[le[[All, 1]], "Export to", "Task local vector"[Range[SMSNoDOFGlobal]]];
];
```